# emacs + screen not properly handling keys

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, emacs, gnu-screen

I'm `ssh`ing to an ubuntu server:

```
cat /etc/lsb-release 
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=17.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=zesty
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 17.04"
```

I run `screen`, and then `emacs`.

```
$ screen --version
Screen version 4.05.00 (GNU) 10-Dec-16
$ emacs --version
GNU Emacs 25.1.1
```

My `screen` has the following configuration:

```
#defflow on # will force screen to process ^S/^Q
deflogin on
#autodetach off

# turn visual bell on
vbell on
vbell_msg "   Wuff  ----  Wuff!!  "

# define a bigger scrollback, default is 100 lines
defscrollback 1024

# Remove some stupid / dangerous key bindings
bind ^k
#bind L
bind ^\
# Make them better
bind \\ quit
bind K kill
bind I login on
bind O login off
bind } history

# An example of a "screen scraper" which will launch urlview on the current
# screen window
#
#bind ^B eval "hardcopy_append off" "hardcopy -h $HOME/.screen-urlview" "screen urlview $HOME/.screen-urlview"

# The vt100 description does not mention "dl". *sigh*
termcapinfo vt100 dl=5\E[M

# turn sending of screen messages to hardstatus off
hardstatus off
# Set the hardstatus prop on gui terms to set the titlebar/icon title
termcapinfo xterm*|rxvt*|kterm*|Eterm* hs:ts=\E]0;:fs=\007:ds=\E]0;\007
# use this for the hard status string
hardstatus string "%h%? users: %u%?"

# set these terminals up to be 'optimal' instead of vt100
termcapinfo xterm*|linux*|rxvt*|Eterm* OP

# Change the xterm initialization string from is2=\E[!p\E[?3;4l\E[4l\E>
# (This fixes the "Aborted because of window size change" konsole symptoms found
#  in bug #134198)
termcapinfo xterm 'is=\E[r\E[m\E[2J\E[H\E[?7h\E[?1;4;6l'

# Enable non-blocking mode to better cope with flaky ssh connections.
defnonblock 5
```

When I run `emacs -nw` outside `screen`, I can use Shift+arrow keys to select text. But inside `screen`, when I hit Shift+down, I see: `M-[ 1 ; 2 b is undefined`. Even with Ctrl+space, which does say `Mark activated`, I can't use Ctrl+n to select a region. These all work fine outside `screen`.

I have these related environment variables inside the screen:

```
TERMCAP=SC|screen.xterm-256color|VT 100/ANSI X3.64 virtual terminal:\
        :DO=\E[%dB:LE=\E[%dD:RI=\E[%dC:UP=\E[%dA:bs:bt=\E[Z:\
        :cd=\E[J:ce=\E[K:cl=\E[H\E[J:cm=\E[%i%d;%dH:ct=\E[3g:\
        :do=^J:nd=\E[C:pt:rc=\E8:rs=\Ec:sc=\E7:st=\EH:up=\EM:\
        :le=^H:bl=^G:cr=^M:it#8:ho=\E[H:nw=\EE:ta=^I:is=\E)0:\
        :li#52:co#211:am:xn:xv:LP:sr=\EM:al=\E[L:AL=\E[%dL:\
        :cs=\E[%i%d;%dr:dl=\E[M:DL=\E[%dM:dc=\E[P:DC=\E[%dP:\
        :im=\E[4h:ei=\E[4l:mi:IC=\E[%d@:ks=\E[?1h\E=:\
        :ke=\E[?1l\E>:vi=\E[?25l:ve=\E[34h\E[?25h:vs=\E[34l:\
        :ti=\E[?1049h:te=\E[?1049l:us=\E[4m:ue=\E[24m:so=\E[3m:\
        :se=\E[23m:mb=\E[5m:md=\E[1m:mh=\E[2m:mr=\E[7m:\
        :me=\E[m:ms:\
        :Co#8:pa#64:AF=\E[3%dm:AB=\E[4%dm:op=\E[39;49m:AX:\
        :vb=\Eg:G0:as=\E(0:ae=\E(B:\
        :ac=\140\140aaffggjjkkllmmnnooppqqrrssttuuvvwwxxyyzz{{||}}~~..--++,,hhII00:\
        :po=\E[5i:pf=\E[4i:Km=\E[M:k0=\E[10~:k1=\EOP:k2=\EOQ:\
        :k3=\EOR:k4=\EOS:k5=\E[15~:k6=\E[17~:k7=\E[18~:\
        :k8=\E[19~:k9=\E[20~:k;=\E[21~:F1=\E[23~:F2=\E[24~:\
        :F3=\E[1;2P:F4=\E[1;2Q:F5=\E[1;2R:F6=\E[1;2S:\
        :F7=\E[15;2~:F8=\E[17;2~:F9=\E[18;2~:FA=\E[19;2~:\
        :FB=\E[20;2~:FC=\E[21;2~:FD=\E[23;2~:FE=\E[24;2~:kb=:\
        :K2=\EOE:kB=\E[Z:kF=\E[1;2B:kR=\E[1;2A:*4=\E[3;2~:\
        :*7=\E[1;2F:#2=\E[1;2H:#3=\E[2;2~:#4=\E[1;2D:%c=\E[6;2~:\
        :%e=\E[5;2~:%i=\E[1;2C:kh=\E[1~:@1=\E[1~:kH=\E[4~:\
        :@7=\E[4~:kN=\E[6~:kP=\E[5~:kI=\E[2~:kD=\E[3~:ku=\EOA:\
        :kd=\EOB:kr=\EOC:kl=\EOD:km:
TERM=screen.xterm-256color
```

Also, inside the `*scratch*`, when I hit Ctrl+q arrow-key, I see: `^@`, independent of which arrow key I press.

Any idea how to diagnose/fix the problem?

Answer (score -1):

Read `man emacs25`:

```
          -nw, --no-window-system
                  Tell Emacs not to create a graphical frame.  If you  use
                  this switch when invoking Emacs from an xterm(1) window,
                  display is done in that window.
```

And, in `screen` start emacs with `emacs --no-window-system`

Comment: Not sure if `-nw` has anything to do with it. I am already running all my `emacs` sessions with `-nw`, that's my default, which I forgot to mention.

Comment: Then, `emacs` is beleving your `TERM` environment variable, and sending terminal ESCape sequences for that terminal.

Comment: Try starting your `emacs` with `env TERM=vt100 emacs -nw` and see if that helps.

Comment: Now `Ctrl+space` then arrow keys selects. But shirt, ctrl, or alt + arrow keys don't. Also, ctrl+q then arrow keys in `*scratch*` still return the same result.

Comment: So far setting `TERM=xterm-256color` (i.e. ignoring the `screen` part) seems to be working for me. I don't know if that will make something else break later.